# Exception has occurred. : CLang. Visual Code

Tags: clang, exc-bad-access

[SCREENSHOT OF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfBFi.png)

I'm fairly new at coding and currently using Visual Code.
I get this error message "Exception has occurred.
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68)" on a portion of the code that shouldn't be changed. I'm assuming it has to do with the path but I need help trying to figure out how to fix it. Below is a portion of the program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char title[100];
    int runTime;
    int idtag;
    double salePrice;
} DVD;

double getProfit(DVD* list1, int len1, DVD* list2, int len2) ;
double max(double a, double b);
DVD* get(FILE* ifp, int len);

int main() {

    FILE* ifp = fopen("dvd.in", "r");
    int numCases, loop;
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &numCases);

    // Go through each case.
    for (loop=0; loop<numCases; loop++) {
    **Exception has occurred.
      EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68)**

    // Read in movies.
    int len1,len2;
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &len1);
    DVD* myMovies = get(ifp, len1);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &len2);
    DVD* yourMovies = get(ifp, len2);
```

Comment: After the fopen line, please add the statement `if (ifp == NULL) { perror("cannot open dvd file"); exit(1); }`, compile and run it again, and let us know the error message.

Comment: message that appears now is: cannot open dvd file: No such file or directory

Comment: you should not read from null.

Comment: OK, so your program needs dvd.in to be in the current working directory. Your IDE may run the program in a working directory that you don’t expect. Please add `system("pwd");` to your program after the `perror` statement and make sure your dvd.in file is in that directory.